# Pandas: fill in the values of column for a user with the first non empty value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is an example of data I am working with.

```
userID | preference
------------------- 
user1  | NaN
user1  | NaN
user1  | coffee
user2  | NaN
user2  | tea
user2  | NaN 
user3  | NaN 
user3  | NaN 
user3  | NaN 
.
.
.
```

There are missing empty preference for some users. I would like to fill in the preference with the first non empty string that is present for each user. My final DataFrame output should look like this

```
userID | preference 
-------------------
user1  | coffee
user1  | coffee
user1  | coffee
user2  | tea
user2  | tea
user2  | tea 
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `first`. `first` will get the first valid value per group if one exists:

```
df["preference"] = df.groupby("userID")["preference"].transform('first')
```

`df`:

```
  userID preference
0  user1     coffee
1  user1     coffee
2  user1     coffee
3  user2        tea
4  user2        tea
5  user2        tea
6  user3       None
7  user3       None
8  user3       None
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'userID': {0: 'user1', 1: 'user1', 2: 'user1', 3: 'user2', 4: 'user2',
               5: 'user2', 6: 'user3', 7: 'user3', 8: 'user3'},
    'preference': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 'coffee', 3: nan, 4: 'tea', 5: nan,
                   6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.groupby` + `Series.first_valid_index()`:

```py
df["preference"] = df.groupby("userID")["preference"].transform(
    lambda x: x.fillna(x[x.first_valid_index()])
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  userID preference
0  user1     coffee
1  user1     coffee
2  user1     coffee
3  user2        tea
4  user2        tea
5  user2        tea
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.fillna` with first forward and the backward. If your data has empty string and not `NaN`, you would have to deal with that first with `dataf = dataf.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf["preference"] = dataf.groupby(by="userID")["preference"].fillna(method="ffill").fillna(method="bfill")
```

Answer (score -5):

Use the method fillna...

DataFrameName.fillna(method="ffill")